# JDBC connection leak

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, memory-leaks, connection

I am currently facing connection leak problem in my code (Java , Struts). I have closed all the result sets, prepared statements, callable statements and the connection in the finally blocks of all the methods in my dao. still I face the issue.Additional information is , I am using StructDescriptor.createDescriptor for creating oracle objects. Will it cause any connection leaks? Please advise.

Code below

```
         public boolean updatedDetails(Distribution distribution, String    appCode, Connection dbConnection) {
    boolean savedFlag = true;
    CallableStatement updateStoredProc = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
    try {
        logger.debug("In DistributionDAO.updatedDistributionDetails");
        //PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;
        ARRAY liArray = null;
        ARRAY conArray = null;
        ARRAY payArray = null;
    ArrayDescriptor licenseeArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(LICENSEE_TAB, dbConnection);
        ArrayDescriptor contractArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(DISTRIBUTION_CONTRACT_TAB, dbConnection);
        ArrayDescriptor paymentArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(DISTRIBUTION_PAYMENT_TAB, dbConnection);
        licenseeArray = new ARRAY(licenseeArrDesc, dbConnection, licenseeEleList.toArray());
            contractArray = new ARRAY(contractArrDesc, dbConnection, contractEleList.toArray());
            paymentArray = new ARRAY(paymentArrDesc, dbConnection, paymentEleList.toArray());           
            updateStoredProc = dbConnection.prepareCall("{CALL DIS_UPDATE_PROC(?,?,to_clob(?),?,?,?,?)}");
            updateStoredProc.setLong(1, distribution.getDistributionId());
            updateStoredProc.setString(2, distribution.getId());
            updateStoredProc.setString(3, distribution.getNotes());
            updateStoredProc.setString(4, distribution.getNotesUpdateFlag());
            updateStoredProc.setArray(5, liArray);
            updateStoredProc.setArray(6, conArray);
            updateStoredProc.setArray(7, payArray);
            String sql1="Update STORY set LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME= sysdate WHERE STORY_ID = ? ";
            pstmt1=dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pstmt1.setLong(1,distribution.getStoryId());
            pstmt1.execute();
            List<Object> removedEleList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            removedEleList.add(createDeleteElementObject(removedEle, dbConnection));
            catch (SQLException sqle) {
        savedFlag = false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        savedFlag = false;

    } finally {
        try {
            updateStoredProc.close();
            updateStoredProc = null;            
            pstmt1.close();
            pstmt1 = null;      
            dbConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }
    return savedFlag;
}




// Method createDeleteElementObject
private Object createDeleteElementObject(String removedEle,
        Connection connection) {

    StructDescriptor structDesc;
    STRUCT structObj = null;
    try {
        structDesc = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(DISTRIBUTION_REMOVED_ELEMENT_OBJ, connection);
        if(removedEle != null) {
            String[] tmpArr = removedEle.split("\\|");
            if(tmpArr.length == 2) {
                Object[] obj = new Object[2];
                String eleType = tmpArr[0];
                long eleId = Integer.parseInt(tmpArr[1]);
                obj[0] = eleType.toUpperCase();
                obj[1] = eleId;
                structObj = new STRUCT(structDesc, connection, obj);
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    } catch (SQLException e) {

    }

    return structObj;
}
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: I have added the code in edit.

Comment: I strongly suggest your switch to try-with-resources. The way you closed resources in your code might leak. Consider what happens if `updateStoredProc.close()` or `pstmt1.close()` throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain more? I am not clear on what try-with-resources mean.

Comment: See [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 2):

Some hints on your code:

You pass a `Connection` variable into your call but close it inside your call - is the caller aware of that fact? It would be cleaner to get the connection inside your code *or* return it unclosed (calling method is responsible)

**Exceptions are meant to be caught, not ignored** - you don't log your exception - you'll never know what happens. I bet a simple `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch blocks will reveal helpful information.

Use `try-with-resource` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650970/am-i-using-the-java-7-try-with-resources-correctly))

```
//Resources declared in try-with-resource will be closed automatically.
try(Connection con = getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

    //Process Statement...

} catch(SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

At the very least put every close inside single try-catch:

```
} finally {
    try {
        if(updateStoredProc != null) {
          updateStoredProc.close();   
        }         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if(pstmt1!= null) {
          pstmt1.close();   
        }         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if(dbConnection != null) {
          dbConnection.close();   
        }         
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Jan, I tried closing the statements and connections by the second method. Still I am getting the connection leak issue. After hitting the method the amount of times declared in my standalone.xml maximum pool, I get no managed exceptions error.

Comment: You see any exceptions in your log?

Comment: Oh - and you call many methods from there passing on the connection as parameter. You need to check them as well (share the code?)

Comment: Yeah... I am passing the connection as parameter for other methods as well. The code I have already shared in my original post. Please refer to it.