# Better null-management try-catch with Java 8

Tags: java

Given the following code:

```
StaticPOIDataType response = null;
try {
  final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
  final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
  unmarshaller.setSchema(getSchema());

  response =((JAXBElement<StaticPOIDataType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(cpoGatewayURL)).getValue();

} catch (JAXBException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  return response;
}
```

I heard of a new Java 8-feature to express this in a much more elegant way by avoiding null-initializiation. But I don't know what to search for.

Comment: maybe: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: in Java 7 you have try-with-resource that you can found here [Am I using the Java 7 try-with-resources correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650970/am-i-using-the-java-7-try-with-resources-correctly) that the only update in `try` that I know

Comment: `return` in `finally` is very "dangerous" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification

Comment: "avoiding null-initializiation" ?? What do you mean ?

Comment: just drop the `finally`, drop the `response`, write `return ...` where you currently set a value to `response`. And after the entire try-catch, return `null`.

Comment: @luk2302  It is more the case in a try-finally, not in a try-catch-finally.

Comment: @davidxxx The catch does not really matter, if you `return` in the `try` and return in the `finally` that still causes unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @luk2302 The OP has a single return.

Comment: try-with-ressources doesn't help because there are no resources which have to be closed

Comment: @davidxxx and the next developer might add second a `return`. Just because the code is working now is no excuse for writing code that is error-prone in the future.

Comment: @luk2302 Like you, I prefer avoiding returning in a finally statement. It is less readable and may be error prone. But saying that it is "very dangerous" is probably exaggerated.

Comment: Literally one of the first results in Google when you type `resource management try-catch` is the thing you need. I think this question was asked without doing any prior work or research.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov i don't see what my example has to do with resources

Comment: You asking about resource management, which is indicated by title of your question.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov resource don't necessary mean `closable`... try-with-resource only works with those. This is just the title that is not correctly defined

Comment: @AxelH, almost any resource interface can be represented by composing `AutoCloseable` and some other interface. Even in cases of resource pools where `dispose()` means "return to pool", the pool implementation can provide `AutoCloseable` wrapper/facade on which `close()` will return underlying resource to parent pool.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov "_almost any resource interface can be represented_" but they are not. So you can't declared a resource that is not implementing it. But that's not the point. read the question and you will see that this is not what OP want ;) .

Answer (score 2):

What your code does is:

- invoke some methods
- if it throws an exception, log (or whatever) the error and return null
- otherwise return what it returns

The cleanest way to do this -- and this is not new -- is:

```
try {
    return someMethod(...);
} catch (SomeException e) {
    logOrWhatever(e);
    return null;
}
```

Some people object to multiple `return`s -- but in a short block like this, it's the clearest way (and if your block isn't this short, do the *extract-method* refactoring until it is).

The alternative with just one `return` is longer and messier, and involves declaring a mutable variable in a wider scope than necessary:

```
Foo response = null;
try {
   response = someMethod(...);
} catch (SomeException e) {
   logOrWhatever(e);
}
return response;
```

- It has more clutter. Think about how much reading you have to do to answer the question "What does this method return if `someMethod()` throws an exception?". In the first example it's right there in the `catch` block. In the second you have to follow the code up through all possible state changes to `response`.
- `response` can't be declared `final` -- I don't think you should use `final` everywhere, but I *do* think it's good to have as many variables as possibly that *could* be declared final.
- The scope of `response` is outside the `try` block. The tidier method keeps that data in a narrower scope, which is always good.

By putting the `return` in a `finally` block, your code does something else -- if *any other type of exception* is thrown, `null` will be returned without any logging or other exception-handling. This is unlikely to be a good idea -- it just makes bugs hard to diagnose: [Try-catch-finally-return clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225819/try-catch-finally-return-clarification)

---

However, more generally, returning null is something you should try to avoid. Your question title mentions "null-management", but it's you that has introduced a null to proceedings. If you didn't choose to return null, you wouldn't have to deal with its problems:

- If null means "something went wrong", don't do that. Handle the exception higher up (if you like, re-throw it as a different exception type)
- If the semantics of the method are "This might return a response, or there may not be a response", consider:

  - Making the method return `Optional<Response>` -- now the method signature is honest
  - Using the "Null object" pattern. That is, instead of returning `null` return `new EmptyResponse()`

This way more of your code can be much simpler and cleaner, because it doesn't have to be full of `if(x==null)` guards.

Comment: @AxelH `Map` was designed 19 years ago. We continue to use it because it's there. But we shouldn't repeat its mistakes. If designed today it would probably return `Optional<T>`.

Comment: Well `Optional` is the opposite ;) It's to recent, at the office, we are still running Java 6... ;-) To end on something constructive, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274792/4391450) as some good argumentation for what is a valid/invalid usage of null. I just disagree to those who said "Never to use NULL" ;)

Comment: @AlexH Java 6 is 11 years old. But it's very easy to roll your own `Optional`, or to use the null object pattern, or to use a lib like Guava (albeit an ancient version thereof)

Comment: @AlexH fine, but the question does not include anything about being constrained by historical decisions.

Comment: I never said it was a problem... You are the one that kept argumenting, so it change the subject slightly.. And come on, it **axelh** :(

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is for optional. here is the below code enjoy

```
try {
        final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setSchema(getSchema());

        return Optional.ofNullable((JAXBElement<StaticPOIDataType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(cpoGatewayURL)).getValue());

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Optional.empty();
```

Comment: It could be that, but I personnaly prefer the "null" version as you only have one return statement in the method.

Comment: there are two return statements 


 return Optional.ofNullable((JAXBElement<StaticPOIDataType>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(cpoGatewayURL)).getValue());

 return Optional.empty();

Comment: That's my problem ;) I know about that logic, but I found messy to have more than one "return" statement in a method.

Comment: Then change the method signature to throw JAXBException exception and then convert into you application Exception and handle it.
 then you will have one return

Comment: i get: reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Optional<T> conforms to StaticPOIDataType

Comment: @AxelH :) enjoying helping :)

Comment: @barracuda317 if you do this you need to change the signature of your method to `public Optional<StaticPOIDataType> myMethod(...)`.  Callers obviously have to be changed accordingly: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for Optional in  Java 8,

Please find a this documentation with nice samples.

https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-avoid-null-and