# how to properly close resource streams in case of exceptions

Tags: java, exception

fortify is complaining about the following code:

```
protected void doStuff() throws Exception{
    try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        ...
        String[] read;
        read = csvReader.readNext();
        ...
    }
}
```

in the case that FileReader throws an exception.  Im new to java, its unclear to me why the try with resources block doesnt handle the case.  How to handle this?

Comment: It does. Fortify is just wrong (unless CSVReader doesn't close the reader it wraps when it's being closed, which would be surprising).

Comment: @JBNizet or if there is an exception thrown during construction of the `CSVReader`.

Comment: `fortify` may be too old to understand *try with resources* - not familiar with it. That construct in Java-6 would be a fail.

Comment: What do you mean by complaining? If you're getting a syntax error, then your compiler is probably not compatible with Java SE 1.7.

Comment: Fortify appears to be correct. As Andy said above, if CSVReader throws an exception, the FileReader will not be closed and its resources will leak.

Comment: does explicitly declaring the CSVReader and FileReader on seperate lines in the try statement solve this?

Comment: Yes. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348893/638028

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to close the lower level reader instance first and then close the wrapper level instance to avoid the memory leak.

> So first close the instance of fileReader and then close instance of
>   CSVReader.

```
FileReader fileReader= new FileReader(file)
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(fileReader)


....
...
fileReader.close();
csvReader.close();
```