# Reading certain double from text file into a list

Tags: java, arrays, list, file

I have this code to read numbers (type double) from a text file to a list.

```
ArrayList listTest = new ArrayList();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-16");
    int c;
    while ((c = isr.read()) != -1) {
        listTest.add((char) c);
    }
    System.out.println();
    isr.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("There is IOException!");
}
```

However, the output is look like:

```
1
1
.
1
4
7

4
2
.
8
1
7
3
5
```

instead of

```
    11.147
    42.81735
```

How can add the number to list line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `InputStreamReader` in a `BufferedReader` which has `readLine()` method:

```
List<String> listTest = new ArrayList<String>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-16"))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        listTest.add(line);
    }
    System.out.println(listTest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("There is IOException!");
}
```

Also, notice the `try-with-resources` statement which automatically closes the stream (If you are using JDK1.6 or lower, call `close()` method in a `finally` block). In your sample code, the stream doesn't close if there was an exception.

Answer (score 2):

As you say that they are doubles, this will convert them to doubles and add them to a list of doubles. This also has the benefit of not adding anything which can't be parsed to a double to your list which gives a bit of data validation.

```
    List<Double> listTest = new ArrayList<Double>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-16"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                listTest.add(Double.parseDouble(line));
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                // Not a double!
            }               
        }
        System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("There is IOException!");
    }
```

Comment: This is the most helpful answer so far. Just a minor point to be aware of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348893/8473028

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you read the input char by char, that's why you see such an output. You can read the input file using `Scanner` in a cleaner way without struggling with the stream readers etc.

```
ArrayList listTest = new ArrayList();
try {
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {
      listTest.add(scanner.nextLine());
   }
   scanner.close(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("There is IOException!");
}
```